# cygwin: vim custom syntax highlighting not working

Tags: vim, cygwin, syntax-highlighting

I have a set of log files that have a standard format.  I've created a custom syntax file for these logs, and it works fine on a linux system.

however, I can't get it to work in cygwin. I have in my home directory the following .vimrc file:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile rc.log* set filetype=rclog
au! Syntax rclog source ~/.vim/log.vim

syntax on
```

and in ~/.vim/ i have log.vim:

```
:syn region logTime start=+^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}+ end=+ +me=e-1
:syn keyword logError ERROR skipwhite nextgroup=logThreadName
:syn keyword logWarn WARN skipwhite nextgroup=logThreadName
:syn keyword logInfo INFO skipwhite nextgroup=logThreadName
:syn keyword logDebug DEBUG skipwhite nextgroup=logThreadName
:syn keyword logAlways ALWAYS skipwhite nextgroup=logThreadName
:syn keyword logConfig CONFIG skipwhite nextgroup=logThreadName
:syn match logThreadName "\[\S\+\]" contained nextgroup=logClassName
:syn match logClassName " \S\+:" contained nextgroup=logLineNumber
:syn match logLineNumber "\d\+" contained

hi def logError ctermfg=white ctermbg=red
hi def logWarn ctermfg=black ctermbg=yellow
hi def logInfo ctermfg=green
hi def logDebug ctermfg=blue
hi def logAlways ctermfg=yellow
hi def logConfig ctermfg=cyan
hi def logTime ctermfg=white ctermbg=blue
hi def logThreadName ctermfg=magenta
hi def logClassName ctermfg=cyan
hi def logLineNumber ctermfg=yellow
hi link cConstant NONE
```

I've tried executing `:source ~/.vimrc` to no avail.  My log files always show up without syntax highlighting.  Files with a filetype that has highlighting built in (such as .py or .c) work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `:au! Syntax`; instead, move `~/.vim/log.vim` to `~/.vim/syntax/rclog.vim`; it'll then be read automatically based on your filetype detection:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile rc.log* set filetype=rclog
```

You can verify and troubleshoot with `:scriptnames`, or via `:20verbose setlocal syntax=rclog`.

Answer (score 1):

From this [link](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2014-05/msg00023.html), the default package that comes with base Cygwin installation is `vi` and not `vim`. When you type the command `vim` in base-installation Cygwin, a text editor is invoked which looks like `vim`, but it is actually `vi`, and `vi` does not have syntax coloring. To resolve the syntax coloring issue, simply install the `vim` package from Cygwin `setup-x86.exe`. This package is in `Editor` category.